# Terraria, goblin tinker

Tags: terraria

While i was reforging my item at night the destroyer spawned out if no where and killed the goblin tinker with the item inside the reforge spot and i didnt get the item back, is there solution?

Comment: Which item was it? Next to nothing in Terraria is irreplaceable...

Answer (score 4):

It’s an odd situation, and I can’t say for certain what should’ve happened in that situation, I think it should’ve been dropped. But, if the item wasn’t and it’s now after the fact, there’s nothing you can do in vanilla terraria.

However, if you’re playing version 1.3.5 or earlier, you have the option of using mods through T-Mod Loader. Another alternative, is using some form of save game modifier, to alter your character’s inventory or your world.

I must warn though that this is “cheating” in the sense you’re obtaining items in a way that isn’t intended, and I wouldn’t recommend going down this route.

Answer (score 0):

It should of dropped. Mabye you missed it. If you didn’t then you can avoid this next time by turning on autopause. This completely pauses the game while you are in any menu. Another thing you can do is check messages in the corner. You probably saw the message but didn’t remember. The message will be for the destroyer “You feel the ground quacking from far below.” You could always re-make the item. I hope this helps! (I also hope you read it)